# Looking for title and author of small press horror anthology

Tags: story-identification

I’m wondering if this will ring a bell for anyone.  I’m trying to find the title and author of a small press horror anthology that I read around 1999-2000.  Here is what I remember:  The cover was a photo of a guy on a hospital gurney, possibly in the morgue, and I bought it at my local comic shop.

Comment: Just to clarify, was it all comics? Just text? Illustrated text? A mixture thereof?

Comment: @SeanDuggan It was primarily text with a few illustrations